# Can't put subviews over MKMapview

Tags: objective-c, xcode, mkmapview, xib

When I try to put a subview like UIButton or UILabel over MKMapView in the my xib file, the MKMapView is automatically replaced with the subview - I can't add subviews on MKMapView. How should I fix this problem? Thank you in advance for your answers!

Comment: Thank you guys! I should add a view not a viewcontroller on the canvas and then add mkmapview. Now it works perfectly :)

Answer (score 1):

You can add Subview on MKMapView,

Below is the code for adding a Button on MapView programatically (For your reference)

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
button.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 120, 60);
[button setTitle:@"test" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[mapView addSubview:button];
```